# jquery ajax data result dont show

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

My js file below;

```
$('#DetailMaxGuest').change(function () {

    var result = $('#DetailMaxGuest option:selected').val();
    $('#DetailMaxGuest option:selected').val(result).attr('selected', 'selected');
    var resultparse = parseInt(result);
    var resultid = $('#resultid').val();
    var dateBegin = $('#DetailDatepicker').val();
    var dateEnd = $('#DetailDatepickerEnd').val();
    var price = $('#DetailRates option:first').val();
    var resultm = $('#DetailMaxGuest option:selected').val();
    if (resultm != "Select One") {
        kisi = parseInt(resultm);
    } else {
        kisi = null;
    }
    var message = {
        'resultid': resultid,
        'data': resultparse,
        'dateBegin': dateBegin,
        'dateEnd': dateEnd,
        'price': price
    };
    $("#LoadingImage").show();
    $.ajax({

        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Product/GetMaxGuest',
        data: message,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.error) {

                $("#LoadingImage").hide();
                $('#reservation-result').html(data.msg).fadeIn(2000);
                $('#btn_reservation').hide();
                $('#btn_liste').show();
                } if (data.success) {
                $("#LoadingImage").hide();
                if (kisi != null) {
                    $('#PriceDetails').show();
                } else {
                    $('#PriceDetails').hide();
                }
                $('#lblTotalPrice').html(data.toplam).fadeIn(2000);
                $('#lblDeposit').html(data.deposit).fadeIn(2000);
                $('#lblTotal').html(data.totalsum).fadeIn(2000);
                $('#btn_reservation').show();
                $('#btn_liste').hide();

            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#reservation-result').fadeOut(5000);
        }


    });

});
```

and my controller return message;

> deposit: "100 $" msg: "" success: true toplam: "1.220 $" totalsum: "1.320 $"

But I cant see any data on my page. js working but I cant see datas.

my razor;

```
<div id="reservation-result" style="width: 100%; height: 80px; display: inline-block; text-align: left; font-size:12px; font-weight: bold; color:brown;">
                                <table id="PriceDetails" style="display: none;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 75%;">Toplam Fiyat</td>
                                        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: right;"><div id="TotalPrice">@Html.Label("lblTotalPrice",new{id="lblTotalPrice", name="TotalPrice"})</div></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Depozito</td>
                                        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: right;">
                                            <div id="Deposit">@Html.Label("Deposit",new{id="lblDeposit", name="Deposit"})</div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Genel Toplam</td>
                                        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: right;">
                                            <div id="Total">@Html.Label("Total",new{id="lblTotal", name="GrandTotal"})</div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <div id="LoadingImage" style="display: none;">
                                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/prettyPhoto/dark_rounded/loader.gif")" alt="Loading"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <input id="btn_reservation" class="gradient-button center" type="submit" style="width: 230px;" value="Rezervasyon yap" />
         }
                        <input id="btn_liste" class="gradient-button center" type="submit" style="width: 230px; display: none;" value="Listeye Dön" />
```

Please helpppp :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

in your code i see this statement:

```
if (data.error) {
```

Should that not be:

```
if (!data.error) {
```

Comment: What is the value of resultM, because this influence the pricedetails to show.

Another problem could be your css. Look at: http://api.jquery.com/show/ and search for display:none

Comment: thanks Raimond. resultM is possible guest option. If select MaxGuest option resultM=this value. As You know ı want to show PriceDetails table. And Its display:none.... I am crazy. I cant solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of issues in your code,

1. What you have return in the controller is not a valid JSON. change your controller to return valid JSON data. It should looks like following

> ```
> {
>     "deposit": "100 $",
>     "msg": "",
>     "success": true,
>     "toplam": "1.220 $",
>     "totalsum": "1.320 $"
> }
> ```

1. To check like `if (data.error)` You have to return it from the JSON. but in your JSON no `error` parameter.

Comment: my json return in controller ; return
                                Json(
                                    new
                                        {
                                            success = true,
                                            msg = "",
                                            toplam = total + " $",
                                            deposit = depozito + " $",
                                            totalsum = grandtotal + " $"
                                        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 0):

Basically You have no valid JSON Array returning. In your case the data is returning in HTML Format and you need to return data in JSON Format.

Use JSON Array like this :

```
 [{
        "deposit": "100 $",
        "msg": "",
        "success": true,
        "toplam": "1.220 $",
        "totalsum": "1.320 $"
    }]
```

or JSON Object :

```
{
    "deposit": "100 $",
    "msg": "",
    "success": true,
    "toplam": "1.220 $",
    "totalsum": "1.320 $"
}
```

Thanks hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks malik. But my json return in controller ; return Json( new { success = true, msg = "", toplam = total + " $", deposit = depozito + " $", totalsum = grandtotal + " $" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

I have no problem json.